# How to return multiple result sets or String array in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to MySQL.

I needed to write a Stored procedure which returns Multiple result sets and I wanted to get these values from java.
For example. I have a table transaction. I need a procedure which return the income based on categories:

```
select category ||' : '||sum(amount) 
from  transaction 
where inc_eXP='Inclome' 
group by category;
```

and expenditure based on categories:

```
select category ||' : '||sum(amount) 
from  transaction 
where inc_eXP='Exp' 
group by category;
```

or optionally I can return String arrays also.

Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't a simple `concat` and `group_concat` help you?

```
select group_concat(sum_as_string SEPARATOR '**') as final_string from(
 select concat(category, ":", sum(amount) ) as sum_as_string
 from  transaction 
 where inc_eXP='Inclome' 
 group by category
)as t;
```

This will result as cat1:12000**cat2:34000**cat3:89220. You can use user set of operators. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation instead to return both income and expenditure as one resultset

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(category, ' : ', SUM(CASE WHEN inc_exp = 'Income' THEN amount END)) income,
       CONCAT(category, ' : ', SUM(CASE WHEN inc_exp = 'Exp'    THEN amount END)) expenditure
  FROM  transaction 
 GROUP BY category;
```

Sample output:

```
|         INCOME |    EXPENDITURE |
|----------------|----------------|
| category1 : 25 |  category1 : 5 |
| category2 : 20 | category2 : 20 |
```

or IMHO **a cleaner way** is without concatenating a category name with values

```sql
SELECT category, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN inc_exp = 'Income' THEN amount END) income,
       SUM(CASE WHEN inc_exp = 'Exp'    THEN amount END) expenditure
  FROM  transaction 
 GROUP BY category;
```

Sample output:

```
|  CATEGORY | INCOME | EXPENDITURE |
|-----------|--------|-------------|
| category1 |     25 |           5 |
| category2 |     20 |          20 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79e5a/2)** demo for both queries